# Python multithread loading animation

Tags: python, multithreading, animation

I write this code to obtain a simple loading animation. The animation is executed by a dedicated thread but it does not work, only print a single view when the program ends. I do not see the problem.

```
import threading
import time
import sys

done = False

class myThread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, name):
      threading.Thread.__init__(self)
      self.threadID = threadID
      self.name = name

    def run(self):
      print ("Starting " + self.name)
      print_loadbar(self.name)
      print ("Exiting " + self.name)

    def print_loadbar(threadName):
      while True:
           if done :
              break
           sys.stdout.write('\r[---    ]')
           sys.stdout.flush()
           time.sleep(0.5)
           sys.stdout.write('\r[    ---]')
           sys.stdout.flush()
           time.sleep(0.5)

thread1 = myThread(1, "Thread-1")
thread1.start()
#MAIN THREAD
c=0
while c<10 :
  time.sleep(1)
  c=c+1
done=True
```

Comment: Works fine for me, after I add `self` as the first argument to `print_loadbar` and call it like `self.print_loadbar(self.name)`.

Comment: With your suggestion I obtain "AttributeError: 'myThread' object has no attribute 'print_loadbar'"

Comment: you should make `print_loadbar` a member function of `myThread`.

Comment: With this chage it is not work fine for me. I do not see animation, the program just print: Exiting Thread-1
Starting Thread-1
[    ---]Exiting Main Thread
Exiting Thread-1, like in my original code.

Comment: then there's probably a problem with your terminal or IDE, which doesn't handle `'\r'` properly.

Comment: You are right, using different terminal it works, thank you.